# Unable to test jenkins plugin class jenkins.plugins.slack.SlackNotifier is missing its descriptor

Tags: maven, jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I make fork from https://github.com/jenkinsci/slack-plugin after add feature I wanna test it, so in intellij idea console i write:

> mvn install

And after

> mvn hpi:run -Djetty.port=8092

In console i have only information about problem with credentials:

> Could not initialize class com.cloudbees.plugins.credentials.SystemCredentialsProvider$UserFa
>   cingAction

But jenkins start. When i try to make build with enable plugin in console I got error:

```
mar 13, 2018 3:59:31 PM hudson.model.listeners.RunListener report
WARNING: RunListener failed
java.lang.AssertionError: class jenkins.plugins.slack.SlackNotifier is missing its descriptor
        at jenkins.model.Jenkins.getDescriptorOrDie(Jenkins.java:1184)
        at hudson.tasks.Publisher.getDescriptor(Publisher.java:122)
        at hudson.tasks.Notifier.getDescriptor(Notifier.java:51)
        at jenkins.plugins.slack.SlackNotifier.getDescriptor(SlackNotifier.java:69)
        at jenkins.plugins.slack.SlackNotifier.getDescriptor(SlackNotifier.java:40)
        at hudson.model.Descriptor.toMap(Descriptor.java:879)
        at hudson.util.DescribableList.toMap(DescribableList.java:149)
        at jenkins.plugins.slack.SlackListener.getNotifier(SlackListener.java:51)
        at jenkins.plugins.slack.SlackListener.onCompleted(SlackListener.java:27)
        at jenkins.plugins.slack.SlackListener.onCompleted(SlackListener.java:15)
        at hudson.model.listeners.RunListener.fireCompleted(RunListener.java:199)
        at hudson.model.Run.execute(Run.java:1783)
        at hudson.model.FreeStyleBuild.run(FreeStyleBuild.java:43)
        at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:98)
        at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:381)
```

I completly dont have idea how i can test it from hpi. Anybody have idea?

Comment: Did you try adding a descriptor?

Comment: No. I doesn't know what descriptor is and how i can add descriptor to jenkins?

Comment: Jenkins javadoc: [Descriptor](http://javadoc.jenkins-ci.org/hudson/model/Descriptor.html)

Comment: Can u say more about this? Or can we speak on slack or somethink? It's my second project in java, i know that language but errors like that it's black magic for me.

Comment: The official support page for thsi error: https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/My+class+is+missing+descriptor